# xamarin.forms does not contain a definition for 'BeginRefresh()'

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm developing a `Xamarin.Forms` app, and I need to filter an `OnservableCollection` of .
I've implemented a **SearchBar**, and the method is quite simple, but I'm getting the problem with a `ListView.BeginRefresh()` method.
Compiler says that ***this method is not found***, but as I can see in the reference, the method exists.

Any clue on what could be happening?

```
    private void SearchBar_OnTextChanged (string filter)
    {
        lvListaCompraDef.BeginRefresh();
            lvListaCompraDef.ItemsSource = productsToBuy
                .Where (x => x.Name.ToLower ()
                    .Contains (filter.ToLower ()));
        lvListaCompraDef.EndRefresh();
    }
```

P.S. I can implement other listview's properties like **Itemsource**, but can't do it with the methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to Clean and Rebuild your project, I have tested this and I can compile with no problems:

```
ListView t = new ListView ();

t.BeginRefresh ();
```

I have this using to reference it: `using Xamarin.Forms;`

also try updating to the latest Xamarin.Forms packages, and change to the stable release of Xamarin. Maybe this can help.

I am not sure what type `lvListaCompraDef` is but maybe you can check that.

Comment: It seems it was a version problem. Updating Xamarin Forms to the last version has solved it. Thanks!